# Create array from randomly extracted data from array of arrays

Tags: python, list

Suppose that I have the following array or arrays:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

What's the best way to loop into the main array and randomly extract one number from each sub-array every time and create another array with them? For instance, in the first pass, the result would be:

```
[2,5,6]
```

The second pass could be:

```
[8,0,7]
```

etc. At this stage I don't have any clues how to do it.

Comment: What you show is a list of lists, not an array, can you make it explicit if you want to relate it to numpy?

Comment: `[random.choice(sublist) for sublist in list]` ?

Comment: Sorry, yes a list of lists

Comment: Not anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have **python lists**, you can use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) in a list comprehension:

```
L = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]

from random import choice

out = [choice(l) for l in L]
```

example output:

```
[3, 0, 5]
```

###### variant

Imagine you want to pick each item only a single time in each iteration, you could also use `pop` on a random position:

```
L = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]

for i in range(6):
    print([l.pop(np.random.randint(len(l))) for l in L])
```

**Obviously, here you cannot have a number of iterations greater than the length of the shortest sublist**

example output:

```
[5, 4, 0]
[2, 2, 6]
[3, 5, 7]
[0, 1, 1]
[4, 3, 2]
[9, 0, 3]
```